# Can't disable Transparent Huge Pages (THP) : No such file or directory

Tags: debian

I need to disable Linux kernel Transparent HugePages (THP) permanently on a distant server running under a fresh Debian 9.9 (kernel 4.9.0-4-amd64).

As [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/mm/transhuge.html) recommend it, I tried :

```
echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
```

but I get this curious error :

```
bash: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled: No such file or directory
```

In fact, indeed there is no "transparent_hugepage" directory in /sys/kernel/mm.

**How could be possible ? How can I get around ?**

I also tried :

```
sed -E -i 's/^GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="(.*)"$/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="\1 transparent_hugepage=never"/' /etc/default/grub
update-grub
reboot
```

but no results, all variables are set to 'y' :

```
grep HUGETLB /boot/config-$(uname -r)
  CONFIG_ARCH_WANT_GENERAL_HUGETLB=y
  # CONFIG_CGROUP_HUGETLB is not set
  CONFIG_HUGETLBFS=y
  CONFIG_HUGETLB_PAGE=y
```

Thank you for all help. I definitely do not understand why there is no "transparent_hugepage" directory and how to manage with that... :)

Comment: Are you sure they are enabled on your system?

Comment: @giacomo : I thought the result of "grep HUGETLB /boot/config-$(uname -r)" (above) was showing that it was. But now I doubt... how can be sure ?

Comment: HUGETLB is not the "transparent one"

Comment: Since this question isn't really about programming per se, you probably should ask it on [su], [sf] or  [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @umläute :  You're not wrong. On another hand, all the posts about TLB are here, so we can imagine that all specialists are here and not there... ;)